# Get difference between two times android

Tags: android, timepicker

I have two time pickers. These time pickers allow the user to pick a time, than it automatically saves that time to two different Textviews. For example Time picker one gets set to 4:00 PM and time picker two gets set to 6PM.

Time Picker One:

```
    // Create Calender Instance//
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Creates New Time Picker Dialog//
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            NewEvent.this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            false
    );
    timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG);

    // Puts It Into 12 Hour Format//
    timePickerDialog.setOnTimeSetListener(new   
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout,  
            int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String timeSet;
            if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                hourOfDay -= 12;
                timeSet = "PM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                hourOfDay += 12;
                timeSet = "AM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 12)
                timeSet = "PM";
            else
                timeSet = "AM";

            String min;
            if (minute < 10)
                min = "0" + minute;
            else
                min = String.valueOf(minute);

            // Append in a StringBuilder//
            String aTime = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ':' + min + " " 
            + timeSet;
            starttime.setText(aTime);
        }

    });
```

Time Picker Two:

```
    // Create Calender Instance//
    calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Creates New Time Picker Dialog//
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2 = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            NewEvent.this,
            calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            false
    );
    timePickerDialog2.show(getFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG2);

    // Puts It Into 12 Hour Format//
    timePickerDialog2.setOnTimeSetListener(new 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, 
            int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String timeSet;
            if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                hourOfDay -= 12;
                timeSet = "PM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                hourOfDay += 12;
                timeSet = "AM";
            } else if (hourOfDay == 12)
                timeSet = "PM";
            else
                timeSet = "AM";

            String min;
            if (minute < 10)
                min = "0" + minute;
            else
                min = String.valueOf(minute);

            // Append in a StringBuilder//
            String aTime = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ':' + min + " " 
            + timeSet;
            endtime.setText(aTime);
        }

    });
```

What I am trying to do is take time picker two's value (6:00 for example) and subtract it by Time Picker One's value (4:00), and put the difference between the two times (2:00) on a new textview (Textview TotalTime;) If you can please provide an example, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get Joda time library. Then for each timepicker create a mutable date object, set hour and minute based on the timepickers. Lastly compare the two date objects using methods provided by Joda, there is plenty of documentation/examples

Answer (score 0):

Joda time is nice, but yet another dependency.

Can't say this will work for every condition, but it'll get you started:

```
      Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
      cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
      cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

      System.out.println("Cal: " + cal1.getTime().toString());

       long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(4, TimeUnit.HOURS);
       second += TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(12, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
       second += TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       long diff = cal1.getTimeInMillis() - second;

      Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal2.setTimeInMillis(diff);

      System.out.println("Cal2: " + cal2.getTime().toString());
```

With results:

```
Cal: Thu Mar 19 06:30:00 EDT 2015
Cal2: Thu Mar 19 02:18:00 EDT 2015
```

Comment: The Joda library is totally worth the dependency, especially considering the use of ProGuard. It's well-tested, and will not be one more thing that you have to debug.